# How to add multiple email address to WP job hunt email plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add multiple emails to the following code. I'm using a wp-jobhunt plugin. how to added multiple email address or to add cc function to the code.

```
function new_user_notification_site_owner_callback($new_user_username = '', $new_user_email = '')
{
    $this->new_user_username = $new_user_username;
    $this->new_user_email = $new_user_email;

    $template = $this->get_template();
    // checking email notification is enable/disable
    if (isset($template['email_notification']) && $template['email_notification'] == 1) {

        $blogname = get_option('blogname');
        $admin_email = get_option('admin_email');
        // getting template fields
        $subject = (isset($template['subject']) && $template['subject'] != '') ? $template['subject'] : sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration', 'jobhunt'), $blogname);
        $from = (isset($template['from']) && $template['from'] != '') ? $template['from'] : esc_attr($blogname) . ' <' . $admin_email . '>';
        $recipients = (isset($template['recipients']) && $template['recipients'] != '') ? $template['recipients'] : $admin_email;
        $email_type = (isset($template['email_type']) && $template['email_type'] != '') ? $template['email_type'] : 'html';


        $args = array(
            'to'         => $recipients,
            'subject'    => $subject,
            'from'       => $from,
            'message'    => $template['email_template'],
            'email_type' => $email_type,
        );

        do_action('jobhunt_send_mail', $args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$to` argument accepts an array or comma-separated list of email addresses to send message. For example;

```
$to = array( 'mail1@gmail.com', 'mail2@gmail.com', 'mail3@gmail.com', );
```

For `CC` and `BCC` you can use headers, for example:

```
$headers[] = 'From: Me Myself <me@example.net>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: name Surname <name@wordpress.org>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: name@wordpress.org';
```

Check out more [examples here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/#using-headers-to-set-from-cc-and-bcc-parameters) and also notice [valid address formats](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/#valid-address-formats).